# Law of composition in a group

Tags: group-theory, definition

Most textbooks on group theory define the law of composition, say $\star$, as a function $\star: S \times S \to S$. The next part of the definition is sending $(a,b) \mapsto a \star b$. This confuses me somewhat. $\star$ is the function, but we're in effect treating it  as thought it were an operation and writing it between $a$ and $b$ instead of $\star(a,b)$. I'm ok with the abuse of the notation, but the definition is circular, defining $\star$ in terms of itself. One definition I say defines an operation $m: S \times S \to S$ by $(a,b) \mapsto a \cdot b$, but then it doesn't define the symbol $\cdot$, which is really the function/operation.

Is this all just an abuse of notation?

Comment: Yes, it is. The second part of the definition is really just setting the notation for the operator. In any particular group, of course you have to specify what the operator *does*.

Comment: It's nothing but a definition. We're just saying that we'll write $m(a,b)$ as $a \cdot b$ instead. Note how much easier and clearer it is to say $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = (a\cdot b) \cdot c$ than $m(a,m(b,c)) = m(m(a,b),c)$.

Comment: There is not anything circular about any of this. There is also no abuse of notation; in fact the definition you give here is **defining** the notation $a \star b := \star((a,b))$, where $\star: S \times S \to S$ (the definition of $\star$ is irrelevent to the definition of this notation).

Comment: Consider the familiar example of addition. We would write $+(a,b)=a+b$ which is just business as usual. One is a prefix notation and the other an infix notation but they're the same thing.

Comment: It is named *infix notation* for a map of more than one argument (two, in this case).

Comment: So in other words, $\cdot$ is another input to $m$, but if I defined $\star$ in terms of $\star$, is that still a problem? My understanding is that $m$ is used to get around the circularity problem.

Comment: @StanleySmith Here, $\star$ is not being defined in terms of $\star$. We are assuming that someone has defined $\star$ already as a function $S \times S \to S$ (or rather that we are given an arbitrary such function), and we are defining the notation $a \star b$ in terms of the given function. I would need to see an example from your textbooks to definitively say why what they write is not circular, but I am willing to say with confidence that it likely isn't.